# How to hide keyboard of ios real device with appium interface

Tags: ios, automated-tests, appium, xcuitest, desiredcapabilities

I want to hide keyboard of my real device from appium interface. Is there any capability that i can use ?
I tried some solutions but it didn't work for me. We are using hideKeyboard() on the code side but i dont know what we can use on interface of appium. Can you help me pls?

Here is the snippet:

```
{
"platformName": "iOS", 
"platformVersion": "13.2.3", 
"deviceName": "iPhone 6s", 
"udid": "udid of ios phone", 
"bundleId": "bundleId of app", 
"automationName": "XCUITest", 
"noReset": true, 
"fullReset": false 
}
```

Comment: Please supply code as snippet and not as a screenshot

Comment: thank you for your commend,i added the snippet to above

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
public static IOSDriver<IOSElement> iosDriver;
iosDriver.hideKeyboard();
```

work for me on simulator and real iOS devices

Or you can try this code:

```
public void hideKeyboard() {
    driver().switchTo().activeElement().sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
}
```

This work when you have active form input element, and this function tap return in button in keyboard

Answer (score 0):

```
self.driver.hide_keyboard()
```

You can visit here to know more about the library.[Hide the keyboard](https://appium.io/docs/en/commands/device/keys/hide-keyboard/)